How to inject circular referenced factory providers?
I have this folder structure:
.
├── libs/
│   └── dma/
│       ├── client/
│       │   ├── client.module.ts
│       │   └── client.service.ts
│       ├── cmts/
│       │   ├── cmts.module.ts
│       │   └── cmts.service.ts
│       └── dma.module.ts 
└── src/
    ├── app.module.ts
    └── app.service.ts

And I have this module structure:

And here is my source code:
~/src/app.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly cmtsService: CmtsService) {}
}

~/src/app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    DmaModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        dmaHost: 'DMA_HOST',
        superadminUsername: 'DMA_SUPERADMIN_USERNAME',
        superadminPassword: 'DMA_SUPERADMIN_PASSWORD',
    }),
  })],
  providers: [AppService]
})
class AppModule{}

~/libs/dma/dma.module.ts
export interface DmaModuleProps {
  dmaHost: string
  superadminUsername: string
  superadminPassword: string
}

export interface RootAsyncOptions {
  useFactory: (...args: any[]) => DmaModuleProps
}


@Module({
  imports: [CmtsModule],
  providers: [],
  exports: [CmtsModule],
})
export class DmaModule{
  static forRootAsync(options: RootAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
    const DmaOptionsFactoryProvider: FactoryProvider = {
      provide: 'DMA_OPTIONS',
      useFactory: options.useFactory,
    }
    return {
      module: DmaModule,
      providers: [DmaOptionsFactoryProvider],
      exports: [DmaOptionsFactoryProvider],
    }
  }
}

~/libs/dma/client/client.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [DmaModule],
  providers: [ClientService],
  exports: [ClientService],
})
export class ClientModule{}

~/libs/dma/client/client.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('DMA_OPTIONS') private readonly dmaProps: DmaModuleProps,
  ) {}
}

~/libs/dma/cmts/cmts.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [ClientModule],
  providers: [CmtsService],
  exports: [CmtsService]
})
export class CmtsModule {}

~/libs/dma/cmts/cmts.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class CmtsService {
  constructor(private readonly clientService: ClientService) {}
}

I am getting this error:
Nest] 642956  - 07/15/2024, 9:47:12 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the ClientModule instance.
The module at index [0] of the ClientModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [0] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule -> DmaModule -> CmtsModule]



The error message you get has a hint of how to solve it using forwardRef. Also cyclic dependencies are a sign of a design issue. I would focus on fixing that rather than figure out how ignore the issue. The nestjs docs on circular dependencies have some examples and you can find a few answers in SO (example)

From the design point of view, as @Augusto says, it could be meaning that a module does too much and that you could create a better abstraction, like smaller modules doing less things but with a good isolation level.

@Pipetus, yes I solved the problem, and I didn't use forwardRef, I changed the design. If you guys are interested I can share the solution
